# Where to put images for AndEngine in Android Studio

Tags: android, andengine

It's normally in the `drawable` folder but when I put them there, I get a `FileNotFoundException`. Shouldn't the `AssetBasePath` be like `"drawable/"` and then texture region `"ire.png"`, right? Please mind me if I forgot to mention anything else.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Inside your project module, find drawable in `src` -> `res` folder.

If you're not getting drawable folder create one and keep your resource there.

```
@Override
protected void onCreateResources() {

    BitmapTextureAtlas mBitmapTextureAtlas = new BitmapTextureAtlas(getTextureManager(), 71, 71, TextureOptions.DEFAULT);
    mBitmapTextureAtlas.load();
    TextureRegion mPlayerTextureRegion = BitmapTextureAtlasTextureRegionFactory.createFromAsset(mBitmapTextureAtlas, this, "ic_launcher.png", 0, 0);
}
```

`ic_launcher.png` is in drawable folder.

---

Also you can put your resources in assets folder and get in this way :

```
@Override
protected void onCreateResources() {

   ITexture backgroundTexture=new BitmapTexture(getTextureManager(), new IInputStreamOpener() {
            @Override
            public InputStream open() throws IOException {
                return getAssets().open("gfx/background.png");
            }
        });
}
```

`background.png` is in `gfx` folder that exist in `assets` folder.

Comment: I know but when I write the path , it doesn't work. Path I'm writing is "drawable/"

Comment: @HeshamHaikal you should create create `assets` folder in path app/src/main/ and put resources into it

Comment: Thanks alot man! By the way do you know any latest video tutorials or website on andEngine ? since all tutorials I found was kinda old

Comment: I recommend you to switch on another framework/game engine. why ? 1. AndEngine not active anymore or contribution is too slow. 2. AndEngine is not cross platform 3. Very few tutorial and many are outdated.

Comment: any recommendation (other than using Unity)? Is spriteKit available on android ? Can I use PhysicsBox with LibGDX ?

Comment: I am currently using LibGDX, Cocos2d-x and Godot engine. If you're java developer use LibGDX, if comfortable with c++ go for cocos2d-x. Godot is emerging game engine, in future it may be number one.

Comment: So can I use PhysicsBox2d or a normal physics library with LibGDX ?

Comment: yes, you can use [box2dx](https://github.com/libgdx/libgdx/wiki/Box2d) with libgdx

Comment: alright , will give it a try. any recommended tuts ?

Comment: Thanks alot , I appreciate it!!